# Creating generic view decorator with an extra parameter

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views, python-decorators

While trying creating a decorator to wrap my application views, I couldn't pass an argument to my decorator.
my views currently looks like this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def some_view(request):
```

the problem is, that in addition of the request, I want to pass an extra argument to my generic view.
I tried this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@generic_view("some argument")
def some_view(request):
```

with this generic_view:

```
def generic_view(argument):
    def _method_wrapper(func):
        def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
            some_function(argument)
            data = func(request)
            return Response(data, status=200)
        return decorator
    return _method_wrapper
```

The problem is that the argument does not passed. I looked for it and argument, args and kwargs and its just didn't passed.
btw i'm using django 1.8, python 2.7.

Comment: I do not really get what the problem is. What is not working?

Comment: The only thing you probably better do is pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the `func` as well, and use the `@wraps` decorator. But besides that, it should work.

Comment: In case something goes wrong, can you post the traceback (or at least the relevant parts)?

Comment: are you sure that you are authenticated? Since those decorators are done first, it will thus first perform filtering. Only in case it is a GET or POST and `permission_classes` accepts the request, it is passed one level lower.

Comment: I am. I just edited the post. the argument I wanted to pass is not passed

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a `lambda` function

```
decorator_with_arguments = lambda decorator: lambda *args, **kwargs:lambda func: decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now your wrapper your function with this decorator. The following will work:

```
@decorator_with_arguments
def generic_view(function,arg):
    def _method(request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(arg) # print arg : Python 2.*
        # data = func(request)
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _method
```

Now you're able to use the `generic_view` as **@decorator** in your `views`

```
@generic_view("some argument")
def some_view(request):
    pass

# output
>>> 'some argument'
```

Comment: Sorry. it doesn't work. when I debug it and check arg value I get NameError: name 'arg' is not defined
I think maybe its something with the multiple decorator? (the api_view & permission_classes)

Comment: It was an example, try to `print()` argument you have passed. in your case, it's `argument` not `arg`

Comment: `NameError: name 'arg' is not defined` actually **you don't have `arg` as argument**. Look a my above answer, you can see my argument named **arg** `generic_view(function,arg):` so that' why I typed, `print arg`, for your case it's `generic_view(argument):` you should use `print argument`. **Dont' forget to add `function` as the first argument.. or simple, just copy paste my code

Comment: I didn't mentioned but of course I changed it to arg.

Comment: please let me see what you have in your code for the decorator

Comment: Doesn't matter. I debug it on the first line in the decorator to check the variables. also print local and didn't get the arg. did you succeed to do so with the @api_view(['GET', 'POST']), @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)) decorators? if so, upload the code.